# How can Chae Young-Shin drive at the end of Healer?

Tags: plot-explanation, healer

In the Korean Drama *[Healer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Healer_%28TV_series%29)*, the whole show goes by with Chae Young-Shin (Park Min-Young) being afraid of cars due to trauma. But in the last episode, not only does she drive, she also hands over camera and stuff to Seo Jung-Hoo, as if he could not carry a camera while riding. But what puzzles me is her driving with the fear she had.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that that with the passage of time and her growth over the course of the show, she has finally been able to overcome her fears and learn to drive.